# Use helpers inside <script type="text/x-handlebars-template"> handlebars template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I use handlebars.js with keystone.js. So to embed values inside my `<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">` templates I add `\` before handlebars expressions. Like this:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <img src="\{{mainImage}}">
</script>
```

The problem is embedding of helper value. I tried to use default cloudinaryUrl helper but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars-template">
   <img src="\{{{cloudinaryUrl mainImage quality='auto' format='jpg'}}}"
</script>
```

I see `Missing helper: "cloudinaryUrl"` message in my console.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you require handlebars.js?

Comment: @GillesHeinesch I added it in the main index.hbs using <script> tag